# how i can block spam website using nginx or cloudflare

Tags: nginx

How i can block website that is using some method to show my site on their spam domain

IE My site url x.com/canon-pixma-mg2170-driver/

The spam domain is; y.com/host-**x.com**/canon-pixma-mg2170-driver/

I am using nginx and cloudflare please help me to block this host from accessing my content

Comment: That'll be tough. Your best bet is legal here, as copyright infringement.

Comment: check the logs for there host, then deny the access. However get lawyers, your question is half oftopic imho